# Updating GridView row on button click

Tags: asp.net

I have a GridView which contains a Link Button inside a Template Field. The code is shown below:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" onrowediting="gv1_RowEditing"
        onrowcommand="gv1_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="inDetailsId" HeaderText="inDetailsId"
                SortExpression="inDetailsId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="inUserId" HeaderText="inUserId"
                SortExpression="inUserId" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("attDate")%>' CommandName="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="attstatus" HeaderText="attstatus"
                SortExpression="attstatus" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="inAttendanceStatusId"
                HeaderText="inAttendanceStatusId" SortExpression="inAttendanceStatusId" />
        </Columns>

    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:LearnConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [attendance]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

The code-behind is below:

```
 protected void gv1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            gv1.EditIndex = 1;
        }
```

On clicking the Link Button, I am setting GridView Edit Index to 1 to make the row editable.

Now I want to save the updated row. On Click of another button on the Web Page, I want to save the updated changes and change the row edit mode to non-editable mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is using the specifics events, this way:

```
protected void gridview1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gridview1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindGrid();
}

protected void gridview1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
{
    gridview1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindGrid();
}
```

To save use the event RowUpdating:

```
protected void gridview1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{                
    GridViewRow row = gridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(gridview1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value);
    string name = ((DropDownList)(row.Cells[2].Controls[1])).SelectedValue;

    //call save method of your business layer

    gridview1.EditIndex = -1;
    BindGrid();
}
```

Remember to declare the event in the gridview markup.